# Search features that would help me find questions to answer

Tags: feature-request, search

The search features provide a wide range of useful options, but there some gaps that could do with filling.

For example, when I'm looking for questions to answer, I might be interested in those that have had at least 20 views, not marked for close or closed, not voted negative, either 0 or 1 answer, not asked or answered by me, with the newest questions first. Search can do most of that, but there are gaps.

1. The search display lacks the information on the main questions display. In particular, I'm interested in the number of views and the rep for the asker.
2. Some of the tabs omit some of the other information, such as tags and answers. The pattern is not clear.
3. There is no explicit control over sort order, just the choice of tab. I would like to rank by answers, for example. The main display has `sort=`, which would be nice.
4. Yes there is AND but there is no OR. What about questions that have 50 views or 2 answers or at least one upvote?
5. What if anything does `relevance` mean? It's the default, and the one tab I almost never use.

Since the new search facility seems to have bedded in nicely, perhaps it's time to think about some refinements.